# How to use a renamed variable for a click option?

Tags: python, python-3.x, click

I want to use [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/) to specify an option, but I want to access the value in a differently named variable.

So here is what I have

```
@click.command()
@click.option(
    "--all",
    is_flag=True,
    help="This will use all of it.",
)
def mycode(all):
    ...
```

But this would override the built-in function `all`. So in order to avoid that I am looking for a way so a different variable is used for the main code, i.e.

```
@click.command()
@click.option(
    "--all",
    is_flag=True,
    alias="use_all"
    help="This will use all of it.",
)
def mycode(use_all):
    ...
```

But the documentation on [click.option](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/api/#click.option) seems very sparse/misses everything/I am looking at the wrong thing?

So how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround by using multiple option names & putting the one we want in the variable name as the first one.

```
import click


@click.command()
@click.option(
    "--use-all",
    "--all",
    is_flag=True,
    help="This will use all of it."
)
def mycode(use_all):
    print(use_all)
```

Which works as expected & generates this help text:

```
Usage: so_test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --use-all, --all  This will use all of it.
  --help            Show this message and exit.
```

It's not ideal obviously. I think we may be able to add it by defining our own `Option` class & passing `cls=CustomOptionClass` in `click.option` - but I don't see any documentation about how one would go about doing that.